# One pop up menu with keyword and user defined completion

Tags: autocompletion

Is there a way to mix user defined completion and keyword completion in one menu triggered by `<c-n>`?

Keyword completion is probably the most useful method, but syntax completion triggered by `<c-x><c-u>` after:

`setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`

really adds efficiency as well. There must be a way to send them both to the same popup menu using `complete_add()` or something similar - I'm just not exactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly; the built-in completions feed directly into the popup menu; there's no extension point there. You have to re-implement the built-in completion, and then can add the results from another completion function, e.g. `'omnifunc'`. My [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) makes this quite simple:

```
function! BuiltInComplete( findstart, base )
    if a:findstart
        " Locate the start of the keyword.
        let l:startCol = searchpos('\k*\%#', 'bn', line('.'))[1]
        if l:startCol == 0
            let l:startCol = col('.')
        endif
        return l:startCol - 1 " Return byte index, not column.
    else
        " Find matches starting with a:base.
        let l:matches = []
        call CompleteHelper#FindMatches( l:matches, '\V\<' . escape(a:base, '\') . '\k\+', {'complete': &complete})

        " Now add the matches from omni completion.
        let l:matches += call(&omnifunc, [0, a:base])

        return l:matches
    endif
endfunction
```

#### General critique

As you can see by the list of completions implemented with the help of my plugin, I favor the opposite: many distinct completions, each triggered by separate keys. At least for me, the overhead of choosing from a long list of completion candidates is much more than the little cognitive processing in choosing the right completion.

Comment: Your plugins are great but the repos on GitHub aren't easily discoverable if you start from the Vim plugins site.